# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in HttpModule

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

I want save users's IPs and activity in a table named logPublic,I want when a unAthenticated user try to access  a speacial folder e.g Admin folder i can add a record in logpublic table  that it have some fields for e,g : ID,IP,Activity,datetime .after that unathenticated user will be  lock utomatically

I am use below  code in Load_Page Event of masterpage in  Admin  folder:

```
$public partial class Admin : System.Web.UI.MasterPage 
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Session["IsBlocked"] = true;
            string ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
            HttpContext.Current.Session["UserIP"] = ip;
            HttpContext.Current.Session["Activity"] = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
            HttpContext.Current.Session["DateTime"] = System.DateTime.Now;
        }
        else
        {
            if(! HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {

            Session["BlockUser"] = true;
            string ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
            HttpContext.Current.Session["UserIP"] = ip;

          }
        }


    }
}


$namespace StoreProject.Data
{
    public class CustomSecurityModule :IHttpModule
    {

     storedbEntities StoreEnt = new storedbEntities();
    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(this.app_DoSecuriy);
    }

    private void app_DoSecuriy(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create HttpApplication and HttpContext objects to access
        // request and response properties.
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;

       storedbEntities StoreEnt = new storedbEntities();

        if (context.Session["BlockUser"]!= null &&  Convert.ToBoolean(context.Session["BlockUser"])== true)
        {

                logPrivate Log = new logPrivate()
                 {
                     Username = context.User.Identity.Name,
                     IP = context.Session["UserIP"].ToString(),
                     Enter = System.DateTime.Now,

                 };
                StoreEnt.logPrivates.AddObject(Log);
                StoreEnt.SaveChanges();
                context.Response.Redirect("~/UnAuthorizedAccess.aspx");


        }
        //ublock != null && bool.TryParse(ublock.ToString(),out isblocked) && isblocked
        else if ( context.Session["BlockPublick"] != null 
                 && System.Convert.ToBoolean(context.Session["BlockPublick"]) == true)
        {

            LogPublic newLog = new LogPublic()
            {

                IP = context.Session["UserIP"].ToString(),
                Activity = context.Session["Activity"].ToString(),
                Enter = Convert.ToDateTime(context.Session["DateTime"])

            };
            StoreEnt.LogPublics.AddObject(newLog);
            StoreEnt.SaveChanges();

            context.Response.Redirect("~/UnAuthorizedAccess.aspx");
        }


        }
    }
}
```

but when i run my application website ,i get an error from httpmodule :Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error in below line

```
if (context.Session["BlockUser"]!= null 
  &&  Convert.ToBoolean(
        context.Session["BlockUser"])== true)
```

i dont have any record in LogPublic table or logPrivate table when i want visit a page in Admin Folder
please guide me

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Module's BeginRequest is too early to access the Session object as it hasn't been yet created by the ASP.NET Pipeline. You'd have to move your logic to one of later events in the processing pipeline (after `PostAcquireRequestState`)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx